# Align browser title from MVC Controller and button on same level

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC application, in which the controller looks like below

```
         public ActionResult Index(Nullable<MessageType> messageType = null)
    {
        base.BrowserTitle = "Hello";
        base.PageHeading = "Hello";
        VM baseVM = new VM();
        baseVM.Products = Service.GetProducts();
        baseVM.OrganizationNames = Service.GetOrganizations(UserSession.SessionData);
        SetMessage(messageType);
        return View(baseVM);
    }
```

On the view the Page Heading comes as Hello. 
On the view i have a button which comes underneathe the page heading. Now I want this button to be pushed on the right and come at the same level as the page heading(which remember is coming from the controller). 
I dont know where the page heading in MVC controller gets it bold black styling from

```
<p class="float-right">@Html.ActionLink("<< Back", "Index", "Home">
```

[image: As shown in the image the Back button needs to move to the far right at the same level as Hello]

This is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: _I dont know where the page heading in MVC controller gets it bold black styling from_ The styling would not come from the controller. It would come from any css and HTML tags used. Can you please provide your complete view? Right now you just have half a `<p>` tag.

Comment: You need to read through the basics of CSS and HTML in order to understand what applies the color. Most browsers allow you to pinpoint the source of any CSS rule applying to any element in the page, starting from "Inspect Element" in context menu. In your case, it's probably the browser's defaults stylesheet..

Comment: Hey guys I updated with more info

Comment: As the others have said this is a CSS issue and not a Razor/C# issue. Without seeing the rest of the page code it is difficult to see what the issue is. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/ ....send all of your view code....all of it!

Comment: Honestly at this time I am only looking how to position a button created using ActionLink syntax in MVC